# How to run PHP with Firebird InterBase in VestaCP (CentOS)

Tags: php, centos, firebird, interbase, vesta

I'm running VPS with **VestaCP (CentOS)** and I had previously installed **InterBase** for **PHP 7.0.30**, but after an `yum-update` and `v-update-sys-vesta-all` interbase was no longer running.

Here is what I've got so far:

- Okay soo with new update the new **PHP 7.1.17** version was installed. Allright, but the interbase module is not running with it.
- And first thing I did was `yum --enablerepo=remi install php71-php-interbase` to install interbase for this new PHP version.
- Tried to restart  but still getting missing InterBase error if I try to use `ibase_connect()` function - therefor InterBase is still not properly installed.

I tried to follow [**PHP InterBase documentation**](http://php.net/manual/en/ibase.installation.php) on this, but I realized I have to compile it and add extra parameter on run, but the problem is that VestaCP uses different directories and libraries so I don't want to mess up my VPS.

Has anybody dealt with this? Any "howto's" to follow?

Comment: Did you install the Firebird client library, and is the extension enabled in php.ini?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel yes I did. PHP.ini has `ibase.allow_persistent = 1` and other parameters. I runned `php -m` and **interbase** module is still not listed there.

Comment: I don't use PHP, so I'm not familiar with all the details, but as far as I know, it needs to contain something like `extension=php_interbase.so` (or whatever the extension is called) in the php.ini (and that extension in the right location) for it to work.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel yeah, lol. That's exactly what I am doing right now. I am embarrassed to admit that I forgot to check extension includes in php.ini file. Let's see if it will work. Thanks.

Comment: Great, if it works, consider posting an answer with the details. It may help future visitors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer is what @Mark Rotteveel already pointed out in the comments, but only with additional steps.

I had to compile **PHP 7.1.17** from source with `--with-interbase[=DIR]` in configuration and then include it in **php.ini**

---

### [UPDATE]

I found even faster way to do this automatically (if only I had known this earlier I would have saved few hours of research).

### Answer

Just run **`yum -y install php php-interbase`** and you will be all set.